# What's a good algorithm for finding if two objects are connected in a 2D grid?

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently in the early stages of developing a game in which players build spaceships by placing individual systems (cargo bay, weapon controls, crew quarters, etc.) on a 2D grid. The "root" part of the ship is the bridge where the captain sits and orders people around.

What I need is an algorithm that can check to make sure that every part is connected to the bridge, either directly or by connecting to another series of parts that can be traced back to the bridge.

Naturally, a part will be deleted it it isn't somehow connected to the bridge.

Anyone know of an algorithm that can do this?

Comment: I think this question is too localized to be useful for anyone else than the OP.

Comment: @anakata Probably, though if he abstracted it enough, it sounds like it could be a graph connectivity problem.

Comment: @DennisMeng you are right, maybe OP or someone else can do it

Comment: Do a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) from the bridge, then delete every part that wasn't marked by the fill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple 'flood-fill' approach to what you want

- Add point A to a set called `scanning`
- Also create a set called `checked` (leave it empty at the beginning)
- while point B is not found and the set `scanning` is not empty:
- for each point in the `scanning` set do the following:
- if it is point B, then stop.
- remove the point from the `scanning` set and
  add to `checked`
- for each neighbor, if it is not added to `checked`
  or `scanning` then add the neighbor to `scanning`